# Do Loop, an efficient break method?

Tags: c#

I have a section inside a method that does something similar too:

```
do
{
    // some query

    // another query

    if another query != null
    {
        // return something
    }

}while(some query != null)
```

Obviously this does not work, because some query is not declared until it is inside the loop. One solution I tried was

```
bool flag = false;
do
{
    // some query

    if some query == null
    {
        flag = true;
        // or 
        break;
    }

    // another query

    if another query != null
    {
        // return something
    }

}while(flag != true)
```

Neither method really satisfies me, and quite honestly I am not sure if they would be considered good coding practice, which irks me. Moreover this has pretty much has been my go to solution in cases like this up until this point, but due to the garbage nature of the flag, I wanted to find out if there is a better way to handle this for future reference, instead of making a junk variable. I should note the other solution which I thought of would arguably be uglier. That solution being to run the query once outside the loop, and convert it into a while loop and recall the query again inside itself, rather than a do loop.

While the code works with the above solution, I was wondering if anyone had a better solution that does not require an arguably pointless variable.

Though I understand that such a better solution may not be possible, or really even needed, it could be ridiculous to even try.

Comment: You don't need the flag in your second example. Just do `while(true)` and `break` to break out if the loop.

Comment: I would typically use your second example if you want to set a flag and finish the function, but not repeat it. If you're worried about the flag continuing to exist, you could wrap the loop in a function so when the loop ends, the variable gets deleted when the function ends. Flags are pretty common in code, and there's nothing really wrong with them.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, Ah, I like that solution. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: I do realize this was a silly question looking back on it. I may of just been a bit sleep deprived.

Answer (score 1):

Having a `break` or `flag` variable isn't what would make something inefficient, it's what inside the loop that should be your concern.  In other words it's just a preference and either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
while(true)
{
// some query

if some query == null
{
    break;
}

// another query

if another query != null
{
    // return something
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
do
{
    // some query

    if some query == null
    {
        break;
    }

    // another query

    if another query != null
    {
        // return something
    }

}while(true);
```